# Gherkin highlighting and behat integration with Netbeans 8.0

Tags: syntax-highlighting, behat, netbeans-8

Is there anyone who has a decent working solution to integrate Netbeans 8.0 with [behat](http://behat.org/), in terms of code highlighting and code-completion.

I saw that there exists the [Cetriolo plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/46231/cetriolo) which is unfortunately not available for Netbeans 8.0.

Has anyone found a workaround on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest this plugin for NetBeans that works also for version 8.x

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/17939/cucumber-features

Answer (score 0):

Some more details to @Ferie's answer:

I indeed could not install Cetriolo on Netbeans 8.2.

Instructions to install Cucumber Features manually (since automatic installation is not available):

1. Download the `.nbm` file by clicking on the "Download" button on http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/17939/cucumber-features
2. In Netbeans, go to Tools > Plugins > Downloaded > Add Plugins... and open the `.nbm` file.
3. Click `Install`
4. After restarting Netbeans, you should see syntax highlighting in `.feature` files.

Here's a feature request for Netbeans to include Behat support out-of-the-box:
https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=226804